# How to multiply UV coordinates?

Tags: uv

I have a plane simply UV mapped and using a texture for the albedo.
I want to have the same UV mapping used for the normal maps, but multiplied by 5 or 10, I don't know how much exactly yet.
Is it possible to not make another mapping on another channel, and just feed to the normal maps a UV coordinates multiplier?

Answer (score 2):

Use a MAPPING vector node to manipulate the values that are fed to it with an INPUT UV MAP node, and in the SCALE fields change the scale of the texture: the values act as multipliers.
Below is the actual node setup.
[image]

Comment: Just for completeness, you can also use a Converter > Vector Math node. Or you can split the coordinates with convert > separate XYZ and then use a Convert > Math node for individual control on each of the vectors, and recombine using Convert > Combine XYZ .